# dummy windows user for specflow automation c#

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests, specflow

we are trying to automation an application which is currently using NTlogin/ Windows login to authenticate the user. At the moment we use the personal login details to authenticate the login page. we would like to create a dummy windows user name and password rather than using someone's id and password. if my understanding is right, impersonation can be used to test with alternative logins? Please help me with the solution on how to do this best

Comment: If you have access to the source code you should be able to setup a fake login or add a real one to the Windows Server.

Comment: Thanks @lloyd . how do I setup the fake windows login. Can i able to do it in source code?

Comment: How about using compiler flags to conditionally compile the application for the CI build so it basically doesn't check the password? And then add some additional code to do some checks of hostnames to make sure the application is running on a white listed server, or look at environment variables (and throw exceptions if these checks fail).